# Gaming Promotional Grant - Winter Holiday Season

Tags: discussion, promotional-grant

> Applications are closed.

Welcome to the **WINTER HOLIDAY EDITION** of the **Gaming Promotional Grant**! Users in good standing can receive one free game on behalf of Gaming Stack Exchange. What's the catch?

Simple - ask questions and post answers to questions about your new game; have fun while helping us create a wonderful database of information on our own site here for the new game. Here's how it works:

> Users with at least **500** reputation are eligible to apply. Fill out a form specifying **one game of your choice** of new or upcoming games for the current big platforms. **Up to 20 users will be selected** from this pool randomly, and will be reimbursed for their purchase of the game by one of these methods:
>
> - Scan and email your game receipt to us; we'll reimburse through PayPal
> - [Steam gift](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?p_faqid=549)
> - Ordered and mailed through Amazon.com (or appropriate national branch)

If you're selected, you'll receive simple instructions via email detailing all the information you'll have to provide to get reimbursed. Because of the gap between this round and the last, as well as the nature of the holiday season, **we are not exempting winners from the most recent round** (winners of this round will not be eligible for the following round, however).

"Big platforms" means **XBox 360, PS3, Wii, and PC**. What games are eligible? As a special holiday bonus, we're accepting any game coming out from **this week up until the end of the month**:

- December 04, 2011: [PC](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=5&date=2011-12-04&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [PS3](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1028&date=2011-12-04&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Xbox](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1029&date=2011-12-04&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Wii](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1031&date=2011-12-04&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore)
- December 11, 2011: [PC](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=5&date=2011-12-11&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [PS3](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1028&date=2011-12-11&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Xbox](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1029&date=2011-12-11&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Wii](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1031&date=2011-12-11&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore)
- December 18, 2011: [PC](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=5&date=2011-12-18&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [PS3](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1028&date=2011-12-18&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Xbox](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1029&date=2011-12-18&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Wii](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1031&date=2011-12-18&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore)
- December 25, 2011: [PC](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=5&date=2011-12-25&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [PS3](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1028&date=2011-12-25&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Xbox](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1029&date=2011-12-25&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Wii](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1031&date=2011-12-25&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore)

Any game released later than this should be selected in the *next* round. [MetaCritic](http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/release-date/coming-soon/) also has a general list of upcoming games, filterable by your preferred platform: [PC](http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/release-date/coming-soon/pc/date?view=detailed), [PS3](http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/release-date/coming-soon/ps3/date?view=detailed), [Xbox](http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/release-date/coming-soon/xbox360/date?view=detailed), [Wii](http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/release-date/coming-soon/wii/date?view=detailed).

### Applications are now closed.

---

This counts as the normal Gaming Promotional Grant type round, but there are still the special changes for the holiday season. Please note them, which I've bolded in the above for your convenience. ♪

Happy Holidays!

Comment: Slim pickings for December releases...

Comment: @Ian exactly what I was thinking, and how will TOR work out in terms of the grant?

Comment: Why would it work differently?  It's still a retail game you have to buy that happens to have a sub to keep playing, right?

Comment: @Ian well, I just hope whoever applies for it intends to pay the sub to keep playing then.

Comment: @yx. the first month is free IIRC, that's enough time for a few questions/answers - still quite a waste though, if they don't subscribe.

Comment: Man, it's a sad day when I'm going to pass on *free video games*

Comment: Can we like...apply for Skyrim still?  That would probably be more productive than applying for any of these games save perhaps TOR

Comment: So, when does the next round start?

Comment: I came here to see if I'd missed the next round starting, but I guess not. xD

Answer (score 6):

The big one, of course, is Star Wars: The Old Republic.  Beyond that, it's a fairly underwhelming month, I'm afraid.

Comment: Personally, I already pre-ordered that one.

Comment: It's pretty bad when I could get that for free and I'm *still* not buying it because I'd never be able to play with the people I want to. Stupid timezones (my guild's all US-based).

Comment: Yeah, I'm not interested either.  I'm sitting this round out for lack-of-anything-worth-a-damn.  Maybe if the window were widened to go back a few months - yaknow, in the holiday spirit.

Comment: I'd go for that one if there wasn't the monthly fee and the big risk of getting addicted, because it is too awesome.

Comment: Yeah, I preordered the "it costs HOW much?" version.  Played the beta and it was incredible.  We should have a GamingSE guild.

Comment: @MatthewRead My friends and I are going to have our own guild, so no guarantees time-wise.

Answer (score 3):

Trine 2 isn't too bad.  I'm not sure if it can be considered 'new' since people who pre-ordered it have had access to the beta for a while now.

Answer (score 3):

I am oddly delighted to see that Oregon Trail is coming out for the Wii. :)

Comment: Gotta get all that content really early before others do, right? :P

Comment: @Ullallulloo I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: Possible sarcasm?  (Since most of us played Oregon Trail 30 years ago.)

Comment: I'm relatively confident they didn't just port the original... Anyways, I'm excited for this one too! It's about time we had some questions about dysentery.

Comment: @dpatchery you're right, it's not just a port of the original. :) and yeah I think this is the firs time in my life I have gotten excited over the idea of dysentery.

Comment: @AshleyNunn: What Jason said, that was sarcasm. :P

Comment: I heard the game died of dysentery.

Answer (score 1):

Just thought I'd throw it out there:

[Postal III](http://www.gamespot.com/postal-iii/platform/pc)

Answer (score 1):

I heard **Guild Wars 2 Closed Beta** will start this month too ([Source](http://www.pcgamer.com/2011/09/27/guild-wars-2-beta-to-arrive-this-year-for-sure-new-footage-shows-public-quests-and-pvp/)). Although I don't know if anyone here can get their hands on a key. We may could handle it like a game give-away :D
Otherwise this will be in the February Grant :)

Comment: There's supposed to be something before the end of the year, yeah, but no news yet. :( Otherwise there would've been much capslocking in chat from me... In regards to February, I doubt it. When I spoke with Anet people at Gamescom, they didn't even have an *internal* release date yet. :(

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes they tricked you, obviously ;p But I myself dont have much hope for a release before Q32012 :/

Answer (score 0):

The "cult hits" are where it's at!

Street Sweeper Simulator, Train Simulator (with [Zombie DLC](http://store.steampowered.com/app/65235/)!), Surgery Simulator, Farming Simulator, Garbage Truck Simulator, Delivery Truck Simulator... and more! Am I right? ;)

Still waiting for *Simulator Simulator* and *Simulator Simulator Simulator*.

Comment: Does this count as Simulator Simulator? https://market.android.com/details?id=net.kairosoft.android.gamedev3en

Comment: @bwarner, you win this round.

Comment: Space Quest 4 did this joke before *some of you were born* :O  oh snap. http://spacequest.wikia.com/wiki/Sim_Sim